# PHP: Obtain image size from an image hosted on S3 / Cloudfront

Tags: php, image, amazon-cloudfront

I have images stored in an S3 bucket, going to a cloudfront distribution aliased to   images.mydomain.com.

In my image heavy php pages have the usual image tags (fed from my server, not ec2):

img src="http://images.mydomain.com/picture.jpg" width="XXX" height="XXX"

I'm trying to find an easy and fast way to get the width and height XXX from this image distributed on cloudfront.

1) I have tried getimagesize().  Here's a simplified function showing what I need to do.  It works for images stored on my server, but fails on images fed from cloudfront.

```
function imagetag2($colorurl){
$img_path = getimagesize($colorurl);
$width=$img_path[0];
$height=$img_path[1];
$imagetag='<img src="' . $colorurl . '" width="' . $width . 'px" height="' . $height . 'px">';
return $imagetag;
}
```

Returned: "failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known ...."   This code works fine for images stored on my server.

3) I am familiar with the "Framework for managing images on cloudfront" to actually resize the image to the dimensions I need, but this package seems like overkill for this small problem.

Comment: `"$colorurl"` is not recommended. Use `$colorurl` instead.

Comment: This looks like a DNS problem either on your end, or with Amazon's cloudfront.

Comment: I don't think it's dns since the images load correctly.  I just can't get the sizes.  I understand from elsewhere that getimagesize() is tough to implement when the images are on a remote server, probably even more so when they are on a CDN

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946803/aws-sdk-php-version-2-retreiving-image-dimensions/15244957#15244957