# AWS SDK PHP version 2 - retrieving image dimensions?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to retrieve the dimensions of an image stored on Amazon S3?

If the answer is no, are there any other ways around it other than downloading the image to my server to which sounds inefficient?

I'm using version 2 of the AWS SDK for PHP.

I've been looking through what is returned from the following code but doesn't seem to give dimensions.

```
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'BUCKET_NAME',
    'Key'    => 'KEY_NAME'
));

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to lack of response I'll presume it's not possible... Didn't r3ally want to do it with JavaScript but this is how I did it.

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="image" />

<script>
// This runs after the image has loaded
$('#image').load(function() {
    // Use the below code to get the height and width
    // document.getElementById('image').width
    // document.getElementById('image').height
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with SDK2. With 1.5 you could do this

```
getimagesize($s3->get_object_url($bucket,$filename));
```

I think this is still possible as long as you can access publicly the image (or you have to find your way around authorized urls)

Obviously, your php must be enabled to open remote files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the db cache.  I run every image filename through a class that checks mysql for a match.  If it finds one, it returns width, height and a preformatted sizetag ready to go.  If the image and size are not found, it uses getimagesize() to return the same info, which it stores for next time.  I also built in a resize method should I want to cheat a bit and resize the sizetag (but not the file) proportionally on the fly.

I don't know if storing the info is faster than getimagesize() as it downloads.  S3 is pretty fast.